# Camera rendering the keyframe view

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I have setup an animation with five different camera keyframes. When I try to render an image (F12), it always renders the view from the first camera keyframe. I changed the camera view for a different view (numpad 0), but it is still rendering the first keyframe view. So whatever view I have through my camera, it still renders the first view from the animation. I have only once camera. Why is this happening ? Please help.

[image]

Comment: that's normal if you keyframe the location of the camera. That what keyframes do. The "lock" the attributes you are keyframing. If you only change these attributes (like moving the camera) that won't change anything until you keyframe that new attributes (location).

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks. I created another camera for taking still pictures.